# Cutting a body in box2d

Tags: box2d, physics-engine

After cocos2d, I'm looking at box2d... And I have some questions:

I was wondering **how to cut a body into pieces.**

1. How do I determine the intersection point of the body with the cut line?
2. Create a new body in some "update_body_method"?

On the second question I have answer, for example between two points create vector from first point to second point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an implementation of this in the C# library Velcro Physics (formerly Farseer Physics), which is based on Box2D:
[CuttingTools.cs](https://github.com/Genbox/VelcroPhysics/blob/master/src/VelcroPhysics/Tools/Cutting/Simple/CuttingTools.cs)

`/src/VelcroPhysics/Tools/Cutting/Simple/CuttingTools.cs`

```
// This is a high-level function to cuts fixtures inside the given world, using the start and end points.
public static void Cut(World world, Vector2 start, Vector2 end, float thickness)

// Split a fixture into 2 vertice collections using the given entry and exit-point.
public static void SplitShape(Fixture fixture, Vector2 entryPoint, Vector2 exitPoint, float splitSize, out Vertices first, out Vertices second)
```

Comment: For simple example  I create one body and vector, vector construct on two points. Collision between vector and body works fine, but I still did not think how to get the intersection point of the vector and the body???  **UPD:** I have one idea, but...

Comment: I believe you can use this method to get the intersection points : b2Shape.RayCast(...)

http://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/browse/trunk/Box2D/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2Shape.h

Comment: I found this method in documentation.

Comment: From documentation:**You can cast a ray at a shape to get the point of first intersection and normal vector** It is only one point, but I need two points. May I use in this case **Contact Manifolds**???

Comment: In Farseer they cast a reverse ray to get the exit point. You can try reversing  b2RayCastInput  points to cast reversed ray to get exit point.

Comment: I broke my brain X_x =)

Comment: After ReBoot my brain :) , I used Ray Cast as you said and everything work fine!